Figure out function param arity and param names
Using the sol Lua wrapper, is it possible to find out the amount of parameters of a given function, and also their names and position within the parameter list?
function foo(a, b, c) end

The information would be:

Function has 3 params
Names of params are: a, b, c, in that order
Optionally, would be nice if it can also tell if function accepts varargs.


I don't know about the sol wrapper, but in plain Lua this code works:
function foo(a, b, c) end

t=debug.getinfo(foo)
    
print("params",t.nparams)
for i=1,t.nparams do
    print(i,debug.getlocal(foo,i))
end

print("isvararg",t.isvararg)

See The Debug Library in the Lua reference manual.
